# pygame for python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I had installed python 2.7.3 on windows 7 and now I want pygame for it. I even installed pygame 1.92 a0  but it doesn't seem to be working . Could anybody help to solve this problem? I had also tried with pygame 1.9.1 but when I am typing "import pygame' on gui, I get an error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
       import pygame
   ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Do I need to set any path while installing?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to download the version pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi.  You can search for it at [this website,](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)  or download directly from this page by clicking [here](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi).  If you download properly, it should run fine.  Be sure to uninstall the old versions of pygame first.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions. Hope it helps you.

Source: https://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter1.html

> Installing Pygame
>
> Pygame does not come with Python. Like Python, Pygame is available for free. You will have to download and install Pygame, which is as easy as downloading and installing the Python interpreter. In a web browser, go to the URL https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml. These instructions assume you have the Windows operating system, but Pygame works the same for every operating system. You need to download the Pygame installer for your operating system and the version of Python you have installed.
>
> You do not want to download the "source" for Pygame, but rather the Pygame "binary" for your operating system. For Windows, download the pygame-1.9.1.win32-py3.2.msi file. (This is Pygame for Python 3.2 on Windows. If you installed a different version of Python (such as 2.7 or 2.6) download the .msi file for your version of Python.) The current version of Pygame at the time this book was written is 1.9.1. If you see a newer version on the website, download and install the newer Pygame.
>
> For MacOS, download the .zip or .dmg file for the version of Python you have and run it.
>
> For Linux, open a terminal and run: `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`.
>
> On Windows, double-click on the downloaded file to install Pygame.
>
> To check that Pygame installed correctly, type the following into the interactive shell:
>
> `>>> import pygame`
>
> If nothing appears after you hit the Enter key, then you know Pygame has successfully been
>   installed. If the error `ImportError: No module named pygame` appears, then try to install Pygame again (and make sure you typed `import pygame` correctly.

Comment: Please don't paste as images what can easily be copied as text. Not only is it mean to those with visual impairments, but it is also an unnecessary waste of bandwidth. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for correction. Will be careful next time.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked for me. `pip install pygame` wasn't working, my guess is that it was installing pygame for python3 and I'm using python2.7 as it's the Ubuntu's default.